How to retrieve task result and use it in dag airflow
I'm using Airflow 2.10.2. I'm defining a Dag which basically does 2 things.

Some core logic that creates a bunch of files
Starts in parallel (order not important) a set of 'worker' tasks

Since the first step is computationally intensive, I'm defining it as a Task that returns the number of files created. This number is important because I have to start as much worker tasks as the number of files created. My code looks something like this:
@dag
def my_dag:
    
    @task  
    def create_files():
        ...
        return count

    count = create_files()
    
    for i in range(count):
        worker.override()()

my_dag()

I don't understand how I should get the value of count in my dag definition. I've probably just didn't understand how Xcoms work (since I've mainly relied on the TaskFlow API) but any help will be appreciated.
I tried pulling the value with xcoms_pull:
count.xcoms_pull(task_ids='create_files')
count['ti'].xcoms_pull(task_ids='create_files')

And without xcoms_pull:
count['ti']

But none of them work, since XComs are defined for inter-task communication.
Error message:

AttributeError: 'XComArg' object count has no attribute 'xcoms_pull'.

Now I've seen that XComs are just a special case of Variables, but there's basically no documentation about it (at least that I've found).
